# unicode value not being replaced

Tags: java, unicode, replace, playframework

I am trying to replace one character that is in a string. I am receiving the string from a JSON call. When i debug the character in question that is causing my issue using:

```
char chr = stringValue.charAt(1);
```

I am getting the value of 12. I have researched this and it is telling me to do a replace using unicode values as shown below:

```
stringValue.replaceAll('\u0012','');
```

however this is not working. I have also tried replacing with the following values and none are working:

```
"\\u0012", "\f", "\\f", "\\p{C}", "\u0160", "\\u0160", "[^\\x00-\\x7F]"
```

If anyone can help me solve this that would be great

Comment: Google's Guava [CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) can help you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replaceAll method doesn't modify the string. It returns a new string where the character had been replaced, so what you need is:

```
stringValue=stringValue.replaceAll("\u000c","");
```

Note that if the character you're supposed to replace has code 12 in decimal, you must convert it to hex.